# Script to run a Google Sheets Menu

Tags: google-sheets, refresh, add-on

I have a Google Sheets with an add-on. I use this add-on to get data from our CRM system. To refresh this exported data, we go to Google Sheets menu > Add-ons > (Add-on name) > Refresh Report.

Now, I want to use a script to automate the clicking of "Refresh Report" item from the Google Sheets menu. This helps us to ensure that the exported data always stays updated.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this @Himanshu?

Comment: I ended up automating this via an automation testing tool called - Ghost Inspector. The automation worked flawlessly.